# Email claim overrides username in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I've written a custom OIDC-Provider and connected it to keycloak.
After the first login in via my provider, the user gets asked to enter a username, email, first name and last name (first-broker-login-flow).

Usually the username is prefilled with what is in the 'sub' claim.
But when sending an 'email' claim, the username is prefilled with the email.

How can I prefill the username with something else than my email, while also sending an 'email' claim?

So far I've tried sending a 'name', a 'username' and a 'preferred_username' claim  -  no success.

I figured out that the IdpReviewProfileAuthenticator checks for isRegistrationEmailAsUsername().
So I've deactivated "Login with email" in my realm settings  -  no success.

Is there any way for keycloak to not use the 'email' claim for the username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a work around. In keycloak I created an "Username Template Importer"-mapper for my oidc provider and set the template-value to `${CLAIM.sub}`.

Not the nicest solution in my humble opinion.
But it works until i figured out a better way to do it...